# Finding percentage of value compared to total in macros excel code

Tags: vba, excel, percentage

I'm writing a program to organize people's hours by percentage of their work in other projects.  Here is a link to my excel document [Excel Document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9QLe.png) and my work so far [Macros work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HElJs.png).  Basically, I have coded enough to calculate the total hours used by a person, but I need to calculate the hours done for each project number by each person.  I eventually need a graph comparing the percentage of work each person spent on the different project numbers they worked on.  I'm having trouble distinguishing hours done by each project though.  Anything helps!

Comment: Please put both the data and the code directly in the original post not pictures.  Put them in highlight the text and hit ctrl-k

Comment: Why did you delete your code after getting an answer?

Comment: I don't think I did? Sorry I'm new to this

Comment: Your last edit, 3 hours ago, titled "deleted 922 characters in body," deleted your code. This was after @ryguy7272's answer, which was posted 4 hours ago.

Comment: Yes, because I couldn't get the code to show up and make sense

Comment: If you go to the help center and seach "formatting code," then the [first thing that comes up](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) says that to format blocks of code, you can indent it four spaces. So you should revert that edit and indent the code four spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use a Pivot table for this kind of thing?  Or, use the Sumproduct function.  Here is a good lik that shows several examples of how to use Sumproduct.

http://www.xldynamic.com/source/xld.SUMPRODUCT.html

If you need all of this in VBA, simply record a Macro when you are going through the steps.

Comment: I need it to be in a code so that anyone can use it and sort it